# Multiple email accounts in a single personal folder in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I have an account with on Yahoo! Mail, another on Gmail.  In Outlook 2007, I've set them up so that I can access them without having to go to their websites.

I've password protected my personal folder, but can't find a way to merge my accounts into one personal folder.

When I want to switch between my accounts, I must type my password again. Besides that, I can't check for new mail messages in both accounts at the same time.

How do I merge multiple email accounts into one single personal folder on Outlook 2007?

Answer (score 1):

After you add your email accounts you can create rules for each account to be moved to a particular folder:

1. Go to **Tools | Rules and Alerts**
2. Click the **New Rule** button and in the **Rules Wizard** window select the **Check messages when they arrives** and click **Next**.
3. In **Which condition(s) do you want to check?** tick the **through the specified account** and select 1st account (i.e. Gmail), and click **Next**.
4. In the **What do you want to do with the message?** tick the **move it to the specified folder** and select a location for it. Click **Next**, **Next**, name your rule and then click **Finish**

Repeat steps for Yahoo account.